# Optimizing this code to find & factorize triangle numbers

Tags: python, math, optimization, auto-generate, factorization

So, I know if I
A) Let this run all night with an Upper Bound of 10,000,000
or 
B) Change the range of n in increments of 500

I can get the answer to this Euler problem. But both of those feel like cheating / lazy. I've seen other solutions to this posted in C, but not in Python.

My main areas of optimization here would presumably be either/or/both some better manner of summing all integers up to a certain value, and not having Python constantly creating and dumping the list of factors for every single number it's checking. Having waited 20 minutes with an Upper Bound of one million and the program not completing, I'm not happy with the way I've implemented this.

```
    for x in range(1,SomeUpperBound):
        n = sum(range(1,x))
        factorize(n)

def factorize(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n > 1 and n % i == 0 and i not in factors:
            factors.append(i)
            if len(factors) == 500:
                print(n)
                print(factors)
    else: factors.clear()
```

Comment: which Project Euler problem # is this again?

Comment: Not clear what you're solving (i.e. from for loop).  Is the problem you need a fast method of factoring lots of numbers?  What are the factors used for?  Perhaps a link to the description of the Euler problem you're solving would help?

Comment: Hint: What is the *direct* formula for the nth triangular number? Notice how it involves a multiplication?

Comment: Euler 11, I'm solving for the first triangle number with 500 divisors. 

Karl - that's instructive, I will see if that speeds my code up, thank you